# Extending prototype of DOM elements inside iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, prototype

Consider this JS code. It basically initializes a CKEditor instance, waits 1 second, then runs `codeToDebug`

```
function codeToDebug(){
    setNodeListProp("attr", function customAttr(name, val){
        if(typeof val != "undefined"){
            this.setAttribute(name, val);
            return this;
        }
        else return this.getAttribute(name);
    });

    // secondary check: all elements on the current document HAVE `attr` method
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for(var i = 0, len = all.length;i < len; i++) 
        if(!all[i].attr) // always false
            console.dir(all[i]); // never executes

    // logs undefined
    console.log(
            document.querySelector(".cke_wysiwyg_frame")
                .contentDocument
                .querySelector(".cke_editable").attr);
}

window.onload = function(){
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
        config.language = 'es';
        config.uiColor = '#F7B42C';
        config.height = 300;
        config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;

    };
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    // wait for async editor to load
    setTimeout(codeToDebug, 1000);
};

function setNodeListProp(prop, func){
    // in case of custom created array of Nodes, Array.prototype is necessary
    Array.prototype[prop] = NodeList.prototype[prop] = function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        this.forEach(function(node) {
            func.apply(node, args);
        });
        return this;
    };

    Node.prototype[prop] = func;
}
```

The `codeToDebug` method extends the prototype of `Node` and `NodeList` with a method `attr`. It then `log`s if `attr` is present on the `.cke_editable` textarea inside CKEditor's iframe. Surprisingly, it logs `undefined`.

---

> **My questions:**
>
> 1. Why isn't the prototype of `Node`s inside an iframe extended, when I am extending it in the main document? (isn't a common global `Node` shared by *all* elements - regardless of where they are?)
> 2. What is the best way to extend DOM of *all* elements - which are present on the webpage document, in its iframes, and its further nested iframes?

---

**Notes:**

1. I've already read Kangax's article (and Prototype's bugs) with extending DOM. But my use case is entirely different. I am only supposed to support latest versions of Chrome and Opera - both Webkit - as such I am NOT worried about conflicts. So, please be assured I've taken the risks of extending the prototype in consideration, but this question is not about that.
2. Here's the HTML (for some reason JSBin or Code Snippets won't show CKEditor): `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script><script>..ABOVE_JS_CODE..</script><textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>` (I locally created a `index.html`)

Comment: When you create an iFrame, it is as good as another window and hence it will have its own scope initialisation. Any override in any scope other than it's will not affect it. Also you can use your own library that would accept a selector and can iterate using it. Its not a good practice to override prototype as there is a change browser also launching similar behaviour causing inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I myself wrote a function to solve this problem. Could be of benefit to anyone looking for a similar solution.

```
(function protoExtensionWork(){
    window.updateAllValuesPerWin = function(win){       
        for(var i = 0, count = protoExtensionNames.length; i < count; i++)
            setNodeListPropPerWindow(protoExtensionNames[i], protoExtensionFunctions[i], win);
    };

    // fill this up as per your requirement
    var protoExtensionNames = [], protoExtensionFunctions = [];

    function setNodeListPropPerWindow(prop, func, win){
        // in case of custom created array of Nodes, Array.prototype is necessary
        win.Array.prototype[prop] = win.NodeList.prototype[prop] = function() {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
            this.forEach(function(node) {
                func.apply(node, args);
            });
            return this;
        };

        win.Node.prototype[prop] = func;    
    }
})();
```

and this is the second piece of code for looking for `iframe`s:

```
function initiateIframeCheck(parentDoc){
    var iframes = parentDoc.querySelectorAll("iframe"),
        win, doc;

    iframes.forEach(function(iframe){       
        try{                
            doc = iframe.contentDocument;
            win = iframe.contentWindow;

            // make sure handler's not already attached
            if(!doc[UNIQ_KEY]){
                doc[UNIQ_KEY] = true;
                updateAllValuesPerWin(win);     
                setInterval(initiateIframeCheck, IFRAME_CHECK_TIMER, doc);
            }
        }catch(e){ // CORS
            //console.dir(e);               
        }
    });
}
```

Please anyone post an answer if they think they've a better and more apt method to achieve this task.